# Create levels based on multiple variables

Tags: r, levels

I want to create a variable called "Factor" which is based on two variables: Name and Day. I want to assign the same number to the same person in the same day, while assigning different number to the same person in a different day.

For example,

```
Name    Day   Factor  
 Joe      1    1      
 Joe      1    1      
 Joe      2    2      
 Luke     1    3     
 Luke     2    4    
 Luke     2    4
```

I understand how to create levels based on 1 variable (which is name in my example code below) but how do I extend the code so that it will also take "day" into account to create levels?

```
b$ID<-as.factor(b$name)
levels(b$ID) <- 1:2
```

Comment: I suspect you are looking for `interaction`

Comment: `data.table::rleid` would also do it

Answer (score 2):

As @A. Webb mentioned you can use `interaction` to create levels for multiple variables.

```
as.numeric(interaction(df$Day, df$Name))

#[1] 1 1 2 3 4 4
```